# How to run PowerShell remotely on Azure Website

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

### Problem

I have website hosted on Azure as a **Azure Website** (not in a separate virtual machine).

I am going to create job that will run systematically, crawl and index site content.

I want to be able to run **PowerShell** on my PC which will work with **remote** date and show progress and result on my PC.

Also I want to create reports on PowerShell. As I do not have dummy boss that needs Excel reports in order to understand data. PowerShell is more convenient for IT-oriented person like me.

### Idea

I have some idea and need validation from community.
Is it a good idea to create PowerShell module DLL, add as reference to Web Application project?
In this case I may be able to connect to site machine remotely (not sure) import module and work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web Jobs now natively support PowerShell scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites.aspx).  You can upload a zip file containing a .ps1 file and it will be executed without further configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Kudu powershell interface?  It lets you run powershell commands on your site directly from the browser

You can find it at:
https:// [yoursitename] .scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell

You'll need to login with your ftp user name and password

Comment: It asks me credentials. I typed my email and password. It does not worked. Can you gave me a some help article link?

Comment: http://blog.azure.com/2014/03/28/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about-2/

Comment: @amit-apple The link you posted redirects to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/

Comment: try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx